# How choose directories list in hadoop configuration?

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I have downloaded a [companion files](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-2.0.0.2/tools/hdp_manual_install_rpm_helper_files-2.0.0.22.tar.gz) scrip for setuping hadoop configuration. It contains `/scripts/directories.sh` file with following block:

```
# Space separated list of directories where NameNode will store file system image. For example, /grid/hadoop/hdfs/nn /grid1/hadoop/hdfs/nn
DFS_NAME_DIR="TODO-LIST-OF-NAMENODE-DIRS";

# Space separated list of directories where DataNodes will store the blocks. For example, /grid/hadoop/hdfs/dn /grid1/hadoop/hdfs/dn /grid2/hadoop/hdfs/dn
DFS_DATA_DIR="TODO-LIST-OF-DATA-DIRS";

# Space separated list of directories where SecondaryNameNode will store checkpoint image. For example, /grid/hadoop/hdfs/snn /grid1/hadoop/hdfs/snn /grid2/hadoop/hdfs/snn
FS_CHECKPOINT_DIR="TODO-LIST-OF-SECONDARY-NAMENODE-DIRS";
```

What do they mean by "list of directories"? As I understand list shpuld be a directories from different HDD and if I use only one drive (for testing purposes for example) it is enough to create and set only one. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally principle in Hadoop is that having more disks always helps, for example giving more than one disk to NameNode lets NameNode to replicate its metadata to more than one disk - so NameNode can survive single disk failure, similarly giving more disks to DataNode's will let DataNode's to strip and write the data in round robin fashion to all the disks for better throughput. Similarly all the daemons takes leverage of multiple disks if provided.

> As I understand list shpuld be a directories from different HDD

And yes it's recommended to mount each of your individual disk to a separate directory, other wise if you provide multiple directories and all the directories are created in the same physical disk then multiple daemons/threads will be bottleneck'ed on the disk I/O.

> and if I use only one drive (for testing purposes for example) it is enough to create and set only one

Yes, for testing purposes it will be enough to provide a single directory that is mounted to single physical disk or even to your root partition, provided you have enough space.